# why tree.export_graphviz(proportion = True) delete the information of the number of sample?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I made a decision tree using scikit - learn.
Then, I am in trouble because the tree.export_graphviz is not so good.
For explanation, I think that people want the number of samples belonging to that group and percentage to entire samples.
However, if tree.export_graphviz (proportion = True) is set, it is somewhat embarrassed that it can be given only the ratio from the whole.
Does it seems something stupid? mental arithmetically every time?
Is there any good countermeasure?
Comments such as "You should use this python library" may be good.

Comment: i think this is a good call, you should open an issue or submit a pull request to the github project for scikit-learn

Comment: I have the same issue. Any update?